# Как решить указанную задачу <<Лестницы>>?

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

> ### Лестницы
>
> У маленького мальчика есть набор из N кубиков (5 ≤ N ≤ 500). Из этих
>   кубиков можно сложить различные лестницы. Лестницы имеют ступени
>   различного размера, следующие в порядке возрастания этого размера
>   (обратите особое внимание на то, что лестница не может иметь две
>   одинаковые ступени). Каждая лестница должна иметь минимум две ступени,
>   и каждая ступень должна состоять минимум из одного кубика. На рисунке
>   приведены примеры лестниц для N=11 и N=5:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Найдите число Q различных лестниц, которые маленький мальчик может
>   построить ровно из N кубиков.
>
> **Исходные данные**
>
> Число N
>
> **Результат**
>
> Число Q
>
> **Пример**
>
> исходные данные   212
>
> результат 995645335
>
> Нужно написать функцию

Comment: Все равно код на чем будет написан

Comment: Кнут, "Искусство программирования", т. 4А, раздел 7.2.1.4, задача 21. Это и есть ваша задача...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за подсказку.Буду изучать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это последовательность [A111133](https://oeis.org/A111133)

[Реализация на VB](http://www.rritw.com/a/bianchengyuyan/C__/20110419/83127.html):

```
Sub Calc()
    Dim n As Long, count(), i As Long
    n = 500
    ReDim count(n)
    count(0) = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = n To i Step -1
            count(j) = count(j) + count(j - i)
        Next j, i
        For i = 1 To n
            Debug.Print count(i) - 1;
        Next
End Sub
```

Асимптотика через  A000009:

```
a(n) ~ exp(Pi*sqrt((n-1/24)/3)) / (4*3^(1/4)*(n-1/24)^(3/4)) * (1 + (Pi^2-27)/(24*Pi*sqrt(3*(n-1/24))) + (Pi^4-270*Pi^2-1215)/(3456*Pi^2*(n-1/24))) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ограничение 500 это совсем мало... На самом деле можно и со значительно большим ограничением решать.

Решение - динамика `F[i][j]` - число способов собрать лесенку из `j` кубиков с `i` последним рядом. На самом деле тут не нужна вся матрица, лучше сжать её в список но это уже детали.

База `F[0][0] = 1`

Пересчёт: идём по возрастанию последнего ряда. Перебираем значение следующего ряда. Добавляем туда. Не забыть проверить что  сумма не больше `N`.

Ответ сумма матрицы по столбцу.

Сложность если писать совсем в лоб то порядка куба (успеет). Если аккуратно то квадрат а то и `n log n`.

Comment: F[i][j] это что функция принимает i,j ?

Comment: Обычно если квадратные скобки то имеется ввиду массив двумерный.

Comment: По моему F буквой обозначают функции.На уровне абстракции сложно понять правильно ли решение.Если бы был код ... :)

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan вы за дурачков то тут людей не держите. Они помогают с проблемами, когда у вас возникли трудности с собственной реализацией чего-либо. А так вы просто хотите нахаляву получить готовый код, не прикладывая усилий. Так не бывает. Точнее бывает, но это вам на Freelance ....... тем более в вопросе метка `алгоритм`, а не ЯП

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский В метке есть и любой язык тоже.За дураков я никого не держу.А для словесных переполохов существуют другие платформы.Тут  Человек либо отвечает либо нет.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, Вам и ответили, причем подробно